# how to configure SQL Syntax

Tags: asp.net, sql

I'm implementing WebSite using asp.net.

I configured Membership Database by aspnet_regsql.exe.

Here is the Database Diagram that aspnet_regsql made.

[image]

I want to construct the data with below column

```
**[U.UserName, M.Email, M.LastLoginDate, R.RoleName ]**

aspnet_Users AS U

aspnet_UsersInRols AS UR

aspnet_Roles AS R

aspnet_Membership As M
```

I dont know how can i make join these tables.

Can you please give me advice how can i configure the SQL Syntax ??

I tried this Query but there is no right result.

```
SELECT  U.UserName, M.Email, M.LastLoginDate, R.RoleName
FROM     aspnet_Users AS U,
             aspnet_UsersInRoles AS UR,
             aspnet_Roles AS R,
             aspnet_Membership AS M
WHERE U.UserId = UR.UserId AND UR.RoleId = R.RoleId AND U.UserId = M.UserId
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you familiar with foreign keys and what they are used for? **Hint:**  Look at `UserId` in `aspnet_Users`, `aspnet_Membership`, and `aspnet_UsersInRoles`, and `RoleId` in `aspnet_UsersInRoles` and `aspnet_Roles`.

Comment: The syntax you use is outdated. Try and use proper JOIN statements. I.e. `SELECT FROM table1 JOIN Table2 ON table1.column = Table2.column`, rather than `FROM Table 1, Table 2 WHERE Table1.column = table2.coulmn`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    u.UserName,
    m.Email,
    m.LastLoginDate,
    r.RoleName
FROM
    aspnet_Users u
LEFT JOIN
    aspnet_Membership m
ON u.UserId = m.UserId
LEFT JOIN 
    aspnet_UsersInRoles ur
ON u.UserId = ur.UserId
INNER JOIN 
    aspnet_Roles r
ON ur.RoleId = r.RoleId
```

The tables `aspnet_Membership` and `aspnet_UsersInRoles` are left joined as I don't know if they will have details in for every user.

Comment: I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 1):

This ought to get you started. You basically use the key columns to connect the data where the values in these columns match:

```
SELECT 
    U.Username
    , M.Email
    , M.LastLoginDate
    , R.RoleName
FROM
    aspnet_Users AS U
    JOIN aspnet_UserInRoles AS UR ON U.UserId = UR.UserId
    JOIN aspnet_Roles AS R ON R.RoleId = UR.RoleId
    JOIN aspnet_Membership AS M ON U.UserId = M.UserID
```

You specify which type of `JOIN` (default = `INNER JOIN`), which will determine what to do when there is no match, and which columns tie the data in the two tables together.

In the case of Users and UserInRoles, it's the UserID field.

I'd suggest you to read up about database joins. Here's a start:

[SQL Server Introduction to JOINs - SQLAuthority.com](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2009/04/13/sql-server-introduction-to-joins-basic-of-joins/)

Comment: Thank you for you help. i need to study more about SQL syntax.